# typescript не умеет анализировать проверку каторая не в if?

Tags: typescript

```
interface IUser {
  user: {
    name: 'aaa';
  } | null;
}

const x: IUser = {} as IUser;

const isUser = x.user;

if (isUser) {
  //кидает ошибку `x.user is possibly null`
  x.user.name;
}

if (x.user) {
  // все норм
  x.user.name;
}
```

**вопрос: можно ли как то дать понять ts что проверка в константе** `isUser` .

Comment: Нет. Никто не гарантирует что x.user не успел поменяться. Да и странно так писать.

Comment: @AlexeyTen почему ты смотриш на все как единственный вариант? Я просто стараюсь минимизировать все и оставить только суть.

как ты думаеш следуеший кусок тоже странен?

`//где s.operation может быть null | ...
const isReadyToGiveResult = s.firstStringifyNumber && s.secondStringifyNumber && s.operation;

if(isReadyToGiveResult) {
  s.store.push([s.firstStringifyNumber, s.operation, s.secondStringifyNumber]);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае typescript подсвечивает все верно, посмотрите следующий пример

```js
const x = {
  user: {
    name: 'aaa',
  }
}

const isUser = x.user;

x.user = null;

console.log(isUser);
console.log(x.user);
```

Как видно, даже если `x.user` присвоить null, ваш вложенный объект `{ name: 'aaa' }` останется нетронутым и isUser все еще будет хранить на него ссылку. В итоге ваш `if` упадет при

```
const x: IUser = { user: { name: 'aaa' }} as IUser;

const isUser = x.user;

x.user = null;

if (isUser) { // прошли, так как isUser не пустой
  x.user.name; // упали так как x.user - null
}
```

Comment: спасибо из ответа я понял что надо добавить readonly.

Comment: хотя в моем случие readonly не поможет особо) но ответ верный)